# Linux で特殊なパーミッション (スティッキービット) を設定するには？

Tags: linux

`-rwsr-s--x`このパーミッションを設定するコマンドを教えてください。

`chmod 6751` ではダメでした。

Answer (score 0):

rootユーザでchmod 6751で設定できました。ORACLE_HOME/bin/oracleファイルのパーミッション設定でした。自己解決できましたのでありがとうございます。